# Change value of var from outside the windows

Tags: c#, wpf

on WPF i have windows `form 1` that open `form2`

on `form2` i have

```
 public partial class form2 : Window
    {

        public int temp1;

        public form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            temp1 =123 ;
            this.tempTextBox.Text = temp1.ToString();

        }

    }
```

on `form1` I want open the `form2` but edit the value of  `temp1`
what i try to do is :

```
    Window newWind = new form2();
    (newWind as form2).temp1=555;
    newWind.Show();
```

but when `form 2` open , I see on `tempTextBox` = 123

i want see there `555`

how can i do this please?

thanks!

Comment: What is the value of `temp1` though... You would have to reset the value of `tempTextBox` to `temp1` to see the change

Comment: You're setting the temp1 value, but I don't think you're ever setting the textbox text.  You set it to 123 in your intialization of the form "this.tempTextBox.Text = temp1.ToString()" but then you set the variable, which does nothing to change the text box.  I imagine if you put a breakpoint in and check temp1, it holds 555.  You just need to update the textbox.

Comment: You are setting `tempTextBox.Text` to the value, not binding it. To setup bindings properly you'll need to a) implement INotifyPropertyChanged so the property change notifications work, b) make `temp1` a property that has get/set accessors, and c) bind `tempTextBox.Text` to the `temp1` property. There are plenty of examples online of all that. Alternatively, just make the set accessor for the property update the textbox value as Aaron said.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to a property, modify the textbox text in the setter.

```
private int _temp1;
public int temp1{
get { return _temp1; }
set { 
    _temp1= value; 
    this.tempTextBox.Text = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  To explain why: you are setting the Text from the the temp1 field during the constructor, then failing to re-set the Text when the temp1 field is changed later.